# Add close caption at swear word from video

Tags: html, flash, video, arduino, television

I spend many hours to find out a close caption framework for restrict to play a swear word from the video.
What I did so far:

If I am not wrong we can do with two approaches

1. Embedded captions – because these formats are added to video files at the point of transcoding.

   a) [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) can control hardware command such a mute and others.
2. We can give supported input file (e.g. TTML or  WebVTT or DFXP ) in different  player  .But with right Flash/HTML player and single file caption.

   a) We can give TTML/DFXP and WebTT with close caption detail in third party player. 
    i.e. [Brightcove](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/displaying-captions-video), [OOYALA](http://support.ooyala.com/users/documentation/tasks/closed_captions_upload.html)

**I am looking for third approach without use any hardware.**

Comment: Just to confirm.. You dont want the swear word to appear in the subtitles (but audio will have it anyway)? Since subtitles are text files can you not edit them in a program like notepad or textpad using **find and replace** option for swear words and replace with a "" (blank space in swear word letter area)?

Comment: yes swear word do not appear in audio and subtitle as well. you can see a such example which is handle by hardware http://www.tvguardian.com/ .